# GROUP BY user to display results ORDERed BY time

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to make an inbox for users. I need to display all threads grouped by correspondents and ordered by time of last posted message for the particular correspondence.
I'm stuck with this sql and don't know how I should proceed:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_mail` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `author` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `recipient` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `date` int(100) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SELECT * FROM user_mail t1 
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT author, recepient, MAX(date) AS Ordered FROM user_mail
        WHERE recepient = '$thisUser' OR author = '$thisUser' GROUP BY author) t2
        ON t1.author = t2.author
        WHERE t1.recepient = '$thisUser' OR t1.author = '$thisUser' 
        ORDER BY t2.Ordered DESC
```

Here's a scheme of what I need to display:

```
Correspondence with User 1        

 Newest reply  - author: User 1    | time: 11:00
 Next reply    - author: This user | time: ...
 Reply         - author: User 1    | time: ...
 ...
 Original post - author: This user | time: 09:30
________________________________________________
Correspondence with User 2

 Newest reply  - author: This user | time: 10:30
 ...
 Original post - author: User 2    | time: 10:00
```

You can see how Correspondence with User 1 gets on top because it has the newest reply in it (although its Original post is older than the other one).

Also, all correspondences should be displayed whether This user started them or the other one did.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How do you define a thread? In the example you posted it seems that any mail / message that was sent or received by User 1 will be mixed.

Comment: Exactly I need to group by users only - messages to and from User 1, then messages to and from User 2 and so on (not exactly in this order, if User 2 correspondence/thread has a more recent message it should come at the top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your user can be in both columns, you have to use the value of both columns in your search and your group by.

Try this:

```
select * 
from user_mail t1
join 
(  
  select max(date) as ConvMaxDate, 
    case when author = '$thisUser' then recipient 
         else author 
    end as OtherUser
  from user_mail
  where author = '$thisUser' or recipient = '$thisUser'
  group by case when author = '$thisUser' then recipient 
                else author 
           end
) ConversationMaxDate
on Author = '$thisUser' and OtherUser = recipient 
   or Recipient = '$thisUser' and OtherUser = Author
order by ConvMaxDate desc, Date desc;
```

The inner query for `ConversationMaxDate` first determines the conversation partner, and then groups by this *"OtherUser"*, calculating the newest date per thread. This works since you can provide *"ThisUser"* (as only then you know in a specific email which one is which in the conversation).

You will need both an index on `(author, recipient, date)` AND `(recipient, author, date)`, as MySQL can then use an index merge. Otherwise it will require a full table/index scan.

Comment: Btw, as I didn't mention it: you used both `recepient` (in your query) and `recipient` (in your table definition) for the name of your column. I chose the latter one; you will of course have to adjust it if you used the other spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following SQL statement, the result will be the same as your display sample.

```
SELECT id
      ,CASE WHEN rn_min = 1
            THEN 'Original Post - '
            WHEN rn_max = 1
            THEN 'Newest reply  - '
            WHEN rn_min = 2 AND rn_max != 2
            THEN 'Reply         - '
            ELSE 'Next reply    - '
        END +
       CASE WHEN author = @thisuser
            THEN 'author: This ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, author) 
            ELSE 'author: User ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, author) 
        END +
       CASE WHEN rn_min = 1 OR rn_max = 1
            THEN ' | time: '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),posteddate,108)
            ELSE ''
        END value
  FROM (SELECT id
              ,author
              ,recipient
              ,message
              ,posteddate
              ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY posteddate) rn_min
              ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY posteddate desc) rn_max
          FROM user_mail
         WHERE author = @thisuser OR recipient = @thisuser
       ) t1
```

Comment: Yes it would be, but the number of replies is unknown actually. I just gave a schematic example, no need for the strings attached to the results. The time given is to make a point which post should be on top, I'll be displaying time of every post. I don't think a CASE statement will do it (except for the author).

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know for every message if `$thisUser` is the `author` or the `recipient`, you can use `LEAST(author, recipient)` and `GREATEST(author, recipient)` to identify a "thread" and use them in the GROUP BY clause of your subquery and for the JOIN condition.

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM user_mail m
JOIN (
    SELECT
        LEAST(author, recipient)    as user1,
        GREATEST(author, recipient) as user2,
        MAX(date) as date
    FROM user_mail
    WHERE $thisUser IN (author, recipient)
    GROUP BY user1, user2
) s ON  s.user1 = LEAST(m.author, m.recipient)
    AND s.user2 = GREATEST(m.author, m.recipient)
WHERE $thisUser IN (m.author, m.recipient)
ORDER BY
    s.date DESC,
    LEAST(m.author, m.recipient),
    GREATEST(m.author, m.recipient),
    m.date DESC
```

But this is going to be slow on big data sets, since no index can be used for the GROUP BY clause and the JOIN condition.
I would make the `id` `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` and use it instead of `date`.
This way you can at least use an index (PK) for the JOIN. And the query will be shorter too.

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM user_mail m
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) as id
    FROM user_mail
    WHERE $thisUser IN (author, recipient)
    GROUP BY
        LEAST(author, recipient),
        GREATEST(author, recipient)
) s ON s.id = m.id
ORDER BY s.id DESC, m.id DESC
```

You can achieve an even better performance using a UNION ALL optimization for your subquery.

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM user_mail m
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) as id
    FROM (
        SELECT recipient as user, MAX(id) as id
        FROM user_mail
        WHERE author = $thisUser
        GROUP BY recipient
        UNION ALL
        SELECT author as user, MAX(id) as id
        FROM user_mail
        WHERE recipient = $thisUser
        GROUP BY author
    ) sub1
    GROUP BY user
) s ON s.id = m.id
ORDER BY s.id DESC, m.id DESC
```

For this query you should define composite indexes on `(author, recipient)` and `(recipient, author)`.

#### Update

You are right in your comment: The last two queries only return the most recent message per conversation. But the first one should return all messages.

However - here is the correct version of the UNION ALL optimized query:

```
SELECT m.*, s.max_id
FROM user_mail m
JOIN (
    SELECT other_user, MAX(id) as max_id
    FROM (
        SELECT recipient as other_user, MAX(id) as id
        FROM user_mail
        WHERE author = $thisUser
        GROUP BY recipient
        UNION ALL
        SELECT author as other_user, MAX(id) as id
        FROM user_mail
        WHERE recipient = $thisUser
        GROUP BY author
    ) sub1
    GROUP BY other_user
) s ON s.other_user = m.recipient
WHERE m.author = $thisUser

UNION ALL

SELECT m.*, s.max_id
FROM user_mail m
JOIN (
    SELECT other_user, MAX(id) as max_id
    FROM (
        SELECT recipient as other_user, MAX(id) as id
        FROM user_mail
        WHERE author = $thisUser
        GROUP BY recipient
        UNION ALL
        SELECT author as other_user, MAX(id) as id
        FROM user_mail
        WHERE recipient = $thisUser
        GROUP BY author
    ) sub1
    GROUP BY other_user
) s ON s.other_user = m.author
WHERE m.recipient = $thisUser

ORDER BY max_id DESC, id DESC
```

While looking huge, this query runs in less than 20 ms on my million-rows test dataset (while other solutions need 300 - 500 ms).
Note that the subquery is the same in both parts. MySQL should be able to cache and reuse the result.
To avoid code duplication, you can store the subquery in a string variable and reuse it. If you use MariaDB 10.2 you might also want to try CTE.

Also don't forget to define indexes on `(author, recipient)` and `(recipient, author)`

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I've tried your last suggestion but it didn't exactly do what I expected - it only showed the most recent message of every user thread. Your advice of using id instead of date was great though, because I already had an auto increment and unique index on id. I'm sorry but I have to accept Solarflare's answer since it displayed the results exactly as I asked.